# Can't shrink the Process Name column in System Monitor

Tags: 16.04

In the System Monitor i double clicked on "Process Name" and now i can't see any other column. How can i shrink this column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I solved it.

Make the window full screen.

Mouse over the stripe at the bottom of the window and you'll get a slider as seen below:

[image: process]

Slide it to the right so you can access the other column headers . Then grab the spot between the process and the next column (default user) your pointer will turn into a double arrow pointing both right and left. hold down the leftt button and slide the double arrow pointer to the left bringing the other headers over as seen here:

[image: proc-cols]

Your end result should look similar to the below and you can resize the window back to normal:

[image: proc-fini]